# How to render an element independent of state

Tags: javascript, react-native

**How do I render an element in React Native, that is subsequently unaffected by any other rendering/state updates?**

What I want to achieve:

I have a button. Every time you press that button, a number somewhere on the page increases by 1. Also, when that same button is pressed, a floating "+1" appears for 1 second after which it will fade away. The "+1" is independent of the total number. If the button is pressed 5 times, I want to see 5 floating "+1's".

I am storing (and removing) the amount of floating "+1's" in the state. However, every time I add one through a buttonclick, the floating "+1's" all rerender and restart their animation. How can I render these elements on button click, but NOT rerender them on another button click?

The "+1" is a class that starts animation on componentDidMount.

**Situation now:**
Buttonclick -> Update State -> Render floating "+1" -> Buttonclick -> Update State -> Rerender all floating "+1"

**Desired situation**
Buttonclick -> Update State -> Render floating "+1" -> Buttonclick -> Update State -> Render only the newly added floating "+1"

Comment: You can control rendering in shouldComponentUpdate(). If it returns false, no rendering will occur; return true - component will rerender.

Comment: @Yossi Maybe turn that into an answer?

Comment: @Davy - checkout this codesandbox I just made: https://codesandbox.io/s/m30ym10m9p - It obviously doesn't show any floating "+1" cuz i didn't want to create those, but it creates new paragraph tags & removes them after a timeout

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher Yes that does exactly what I need. I'm trying to understand your code and it looks clear to me, but could you explain maybe a little about what you are doing with the timeOutId? You have the timeoutId, which has an ID of null which then sets the ID to itself - that part is a little confusing to me. Also feel free to turn this into an answer so I can accredit you

Comment: @Davy added the code + explanation :D Let me know if you need more clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little somethin' somethin' that I drew up, and hopefully it can help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/m30ym10m9p

Basically, you have some `elems` in an array stored in state, you have a `<button>` which adds new elements to said array, and every time you add an element, you also create a `setTimeout` which removes itself from the array once the timeout is over. Here's how the code looks:

Set a super basic array in state:

```
state = {
  elems: []
};
```

Rendering elements from state:

```
render() {
  // pretty basic, just a normal button to add elements & map through state to render
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={this.addElem}>Add elem!</button>
      {this.state.elems.map((elem, i) => (
        <p key={i}>{elem.text}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Add element to state (explained in more detail at the bottom of the post):

```
addElem = () => {
  const elems = [...this.state.elems];

  // create empty id to be filled later
  let timeoutProps = { id: null };

  // set timeout for element to be removed
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(
    ({ id }) => {
      this.removeElem(id);
    },
    1000,
    timeoutProps
  );

  // quickly add timeout id to props, which will get passed back in to timeout
  timeoutProps["id"] = timeoutId;

  // add new element to "elems" array
  elems.push({
    text: `New!! (${timeoutId})`,
    id: timeoutId
  });

  // update state
  this.setState({ elems });
};
```

Remove element from state:

```
removeElem = id => {
  let elems = [...this.state.elems].filter(elem => elem.id !== id);
  this.setState({ elems });
};
```

The `render` is pretty simple, but let me know if you have questions on that. The funky part in my code is the `addElem` method. I wanted to make sure that the `timeoutId` was saved once the timeout was created, and after the timeout expired, the `removeElem` function could be called with that timeout's id passed to it.

In order to pass the timeout's id into `removeElem` (after the timeout expires), I had to be a bit tricky with javascript objects.

- First, we create an object with an empty `id` prop: `let timeoutProps = { id: null };`

  - **Note**: I'm using an object here because this will mean the `timeoutProps` variable is just a pointer to the data `{id: null}`. So it can be changed elsewhere and any future use of `timeoutProps` will use the updated data.
- Next, we pass this to the `setTimeout` callback.

  - **Note**: at this point, the callback hasn't been fired!
- Finally, we edit the `timeoutProps` property `id` to the timeoutId

  - **Note**: Since the `setTimeout` callback *still* hasn't been fired, the `timeoutProps` variable now points to the updated data `{id: timeoutId}`
- Once the `setTimeout` callback is triggered, `setTimeout` will now have access to `{id: timeoutId}`, and it will be able to pass the `timeoutId` to `removeElem`.

Hopefully this makes sense? It's one of the confusing (and fun) things about Javascript :D Happy to explain more if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I used React Native, but the principle is the same (just swap out the p tag for a Text tag)

Comment: Aah yeah good point, it should translate easily to React Native :)

Answer (score 0):

You can control rendering in `shouldComponentUpdate()`.  The decision whether to render or not is up to you: If `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, no rendering will occur; If it returns true - component will rerender.